# Report Builder 3.0 Crash When Creating Dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

Morning folks.

This problem is very isolated but very annoying. It only happens with one customer I do work for, and can happen when creating new datasets or amending existing ones, but doesnt happen every time.

So lets start with a new dataset. I right-click and Add Dataset, I give the dataset a name, select the data source and then select Stored Procedure. This is where the fun begins. I start to type the SP name and BOOM, Report Builder crashes. I know I can just pick off the list but in the case of this client, the list of SPs is massive, so starting to type the name narrows down the list.

This can also happen if I amended the name of an SP within an existing dataset.

It has to be something to do with configuration as this doesnt happen with any of my other customers. The only difference with this site is they use Citrix but I cant see how that would affect this.

So, Report Builder 3.0 connecting to a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems not the issue on SSRS side, please let the user connect the database and execute the SP directly to check the performance. It also can be some hardware or configuration issue on that client's machine. You can suggest him use Process Monitor to fetch some detail information.